# In Visual Studio 2017 when I try to delete a SQL table In SSOX why do I get "Cannot delete database object due to an open object definition window."

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

There is clearly no other window open in the IDE. Searching google only returns people asking the same question. Are you only supposed to Script As->drop tables to remove them? If so what is the delete option for?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Look again. Do you see the properties window? What object is it displaying properties for? Your table.

Comment: @SMor lol, Well that fixed the error but now nothing happens after I right click delete the table. You don't off the top of your head know how to do that?

Comment: Three years later and still get this error in VS2019. Is there a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to Script As->drop tables. The only way I found to get past this was to close and re-open Visual Studio, and try again (the universal panacea for many VS issues). But I am not sure what the underlying issue is that causes this.